# Android Studio - Recycler View not showing sent messages on a messaging application

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, firebase-cloud-messaging, messaging

I am currently trying to learn Android Studio in general and I am using Java, I have started to recreate a messaging application from a YouTube tutorial(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F_UemS493IM&t=6882s)

My problem is that when I write a message to the user, everything works on the server(Firebase) as I can see that the user profile is created, the profile picture and name is uploaded and the message are sent to a profile but the messages are not showing on the app when they are sent. [Chat Activity Screen]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w25vS.png .
I have been trying to fix this issue for the last 4 weeks now and I can't figure anything out, not even by comparing a finished version of the project which is available to download in the YouTube video.

I have tried:

-Comparing the code on the ChatActivity screen to see if I missed anything(as this is the screen that has the messages), I went over the code 5 times but couldn't find anything.

-I have compared the Adapters to see if they are all linked.

-I modified the recyclerview XML code to see if maybe it is set to invisible or something else.

-I have set the recylerview to 'wrap_content' in the XML code as this was suggested on similar issues.

-I have also tried re-arranging the layout to see if it is blocked by any elements.

This is the code for the ChatActivity:

```
ActivityChatBinding binding;
MessagesAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<Message> messages;

String senderRoom, receiverRoom;

FirebaseDatabase database;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityChatBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    messages = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new MessagesAdapter(this, messages, senderRoom, receiverRoom);
    binding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
    String receiverUid = getIntent().getStringExtra("uid");
    String senderUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();

    senderRoom = senderUid + receiverUid;
    receiverRoom = receiverUid + senderUid;


    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    database.getReference().child("chats")
            .child(senderRoom)
            .child("messages")
            .push()
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    messages.clear();
                    for(DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Message message = snapshot1.getValue(Message.class);
                        messages.add(message);
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });

    binding.sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String messageTxt = binding.messageBox.getText().toString();

            Date date = new Date();
            Message message = new Message(messageTxt, senderUid, date.getTime());
            binding.messageBox.setText("");

            String randomKey = database.getReference().push().getKey();

            HashMap<String, Object> lastMsgObj = new HashMap<>();
            lastMsgObj.put("lastMsg", message.getMessage());
            lastMsgObj.put("lastMsgTime", date.getTime());

            database.getReference().child("chats").child(senderRoom).updateChildren(lastMsgObj);
            database.getReference().child("chats").child(receiverRoom).updateChildren(lastMsgObj);

            database.getReference().child("chats")
                    .child(senderRoom)
                    .child("messages")
                    .child(randomKey)
                    .setValue(message).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    database.getReference().child("chats")
                            .child(receiverRoom)
                            .child("messages")
                            .child(randomKey)
                            .setValue(message).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            });

        }
    });
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(name);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    finish();
    return super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
```

This is the code for the Message Adapter:

Context context;
ArrayList messages;

```
final int ITEM_SENT = 1;
final int ITEM_RECEIVE = 2;

String senderRoom;
String receiverRoom;

public MessagesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Message> messages, String senderRoom, String receiverRoom) {
    this.context = context;
    this.messages = messages;
    this.senderRoom = senderRoom;
    this.receiverRoom = receiverRoom;


}


@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == ITEM_SENT) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_sent, parent, false);
        return new SentViewHolder(view);
    } else {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_receive, parent, false);
        return new ReceiverViewHolder(view);
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Message message = messages.get(position);
    if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid().equals(message.getSenderId())) {
        return ITEM_SENT;
    } else {
        return ITEM_RECEIVE;
    }
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Message message = messages.get(position);

    if(holder.getClass() == SentViewHolder.class) {
        SentViewHolder viewHolder = (SentViewHolder)holder;
        viewHolder.binding.message.setText(message.getMessage());
    } else {
        ReceiverViewHolder viewHolder = (ReceiverViewHolder) holder;
        viewHolder.binding.message.setText(message.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return messages.size();
}

public class SentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ItemSentBinding binding;
    public SentViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        binding = ItemSentBinding.bind(itemView);
    }
}

public class ReceiverViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ItemReceiveBinding binding;
    public ReceiverViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        binding = ItemReceiveBinding.bind(itemView);

    }
}
```

This is the code for the User Adapter:

```
Context context;
    ArrayList<User> users;

    public UsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> users) {
        this.context = context;
        this.users = users;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_conversation, parent, false);

        return new UsersViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersViewHolder holder, int position) {
     User user = users.get(position);

     holder.binding.Username.setText(user.getName());

        Glide.with(context).load(user.getProfileImage())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.avatar)
        .into(holder.binding.profile);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChatActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", user.getName());
                intent.putExtra("uid", user.getUid());
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return users.size();
    }

    public class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
RowConversationBinding binding;
        public UsersViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            binding = RowConversationBinding.bind(itemView);
        }
    }
```

This is the XML code for the ChatActivity:

```
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activities.ChatActivity">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="321dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/messageBox"
                android:layout_width="246dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Type a message..."
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:padding="8dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/attachment"
                android:layout_width="71dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#00FFFFFF"

                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_attachment" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/camera"
                android:layout_width="71dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_camera" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="524dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.666"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sendBtn"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FF5722"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: does the receiver message work?

Comment: Hi, it does, the app is fixed, I have posted an answer below. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The app was fixed by:

- Referencing the database before the binding.sent button
- The removal of line 57 .Push()
- Adding message.setMessageId(snapshot1.getKey()); in your database.get ref